# Ignoring extra keys in a hash passed in to create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Does rails provide a way to ignore extra keys that are passed in to create. Supposed User has two attributes, first_name and last_name. When I do

```
User.create({ :first_name => "first", :last_name => "last", :age => 10})
```

that line gives me an UknonwnAttributeError. Well, that makes sense, it happens cause age is not one of the attributes.

But is there a way to just ignore key-value pair that is not one of the attributes for User?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either what sameera207 said or

```
hash.keep_if { |k,v| User.attribute_names.include?(k.to_s) }
```

Ultimately you could override your User model's create method to reject unexacting attributes but i think that's not appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you could do this by declaring a virtual attribute as 'age'

Example:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :age
end
```

Comment: age does not exist that is why i think it should be ignored when trying to create